# Regularity of Feynman-Kac formula for a simple diffusion

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, elliptic-pde

Let consider the diffusion process given by:

$$dX_t = \alpha(X_t) dW_t$$

where $\alpha(x) = \alpha_1\mathbf{1}_{x\geq 0} + \alpha_2\mathbf{1}_{x< 0}$ ($\alpha_1,\alpha_2>0$) and $W$ a Wiener process.

By the Feynman-Kac formula, it is known that the function given by:

$$u(t,x) = \mathbb{E}[\phi(X_T)\mid X_t = x]$$

solves the PDE:

$$u_t = (\sqrt{\alpha}u_x)_x$$
with final condition $u(T,x) = \phi(x) \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.

### My question

What can we say about the regularity of $u$ ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean $dX_t = \alpha(X_t)dW_t$ where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion?

Comment: Yes @ChristopheLeuridan, thank you!